# Custom Taxonomy Not Showing in Front-End When Outputting a Custom Post Type with WP_Query()

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type that I'm importing into the front page of the site with `WP_Query()`, but I can't seem to get the custom taxonomy to show.

I've placed a div in the HTML and inside this I'm calling `the_category()`, but nothing is being outputted to the front end.

The taxonomy is showing in the back end and I've added a custom taxonomy (category) to all of the three posts I want to show.

```
<?php 

    $homePageNews = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'post_type'=> 'news'
    ));

    while($homePageNews->have_posts()){
        $homePageNews->the_post(); ?>

            <article class="article top-article lastest-top-article">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', 
                ['class' => 'image latest-top-image hover-class']); ?>

                <div class="cat"><?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></div>

                <div class="content-wrapper content-wrapper-mobile-padding">
                    <h3 class="td no-bottom-margin hover-class"><a class="top-latest-heading" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <hr>
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></h3></p>
                </div>
            </article>


<?php } ?>

<?php  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: does your custom post_type use a real 'custom' taxonomy or the generic taxonomy 'category'? https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/categories-tags-custom-taxonomies/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your explanation above I understood that you want to show custom taxonomy you have registered for that post type.

[the_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_category/); fetches the default category that comes with the default post.

For rendering custom taxonomy you need to add something like this:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'your custom taxonomy slug' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
 echo $term->name;
}
```

Comment: Hi @divyaT  — this does show the term, but it's not an active link. How do I get it so it shows each taxonomy as an active link so when I click on each custom taxonomy it goes to an archive page for said taxonomy?

Comment: Hi @TheChewy, Firstly you need to create the template 
for default category - taxonomy.php file 
if it's custom taxonomy - taxonomy-cpt-name.php

You can find more details about template hierarchy [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)                       
For having an active link on term, please use this:

`foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
 $cat_name = $term->name .' | ';
 $category_link = get_term_link($term);?>
 <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) ?>">
            <?php echo $term->name; ?>
        </a><?php
}?>`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get custom taxonomy comma separated listing than we can go with WordPress inbuilt function [`get_the_term_list()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list)

```
get_the_term_list( $id, $taxonomy, $before, $sep, $after )
$id        : Post ID
$taxonomy  : Name of taxonomy
$before    : Leading text
$sep       : String to separate tags
$after     : Trailing text

for example,
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'people', 'People: ', ', ' ); ?>
```

or we can go with

```
$term_obj_list = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'taxonomy' );
$terms_string = join(', ', wp_list_pluck($term_obj_list, 'name'));
```